# how find datacenter using a ip address related to that datacenter?

Tags: ip-address, datacenter, find, reseller

I have a vds and it's really good!
I have some problems with my reseller of that server because of their support.
I want to buy a server from that datacenter directly.
How can I find that datacenter using an IP address related to that datacenter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases the owner of the datacenter will be the same company that owns the IP subnet to which your IP belongs. IP subnets are assigned and kept track of by a few RIRs (Regional Internet Registries), one per geographical region: ARIN for North America, RIPE for Europe, APNIC for asia-pacific, AFRINIC for Africa, LACNIC for Latin America, etc.
You can query these registries just like DNS, using whois:
`whois -h whois.arin.net 87.65.43.21`

Or, as others pointed out, there are plenty of free web sites that query multiple RIRs at once and present you the results, like http://whois.arin.net.

Answer (score 2):

Just use one of a thousand websites, which gives you an information about the IP address 
owner:

(See the ISP field).

http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to do a whois on the IP.
Here's a site that offers it: http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp

Also, if you run Linux, you can type whois *ipaddress* and that'll give you the info as well.